# Optimise 1D cutting stock problem - maximum waste that can be removed with n cuts

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

The problem statement can be made as follows. There is a 1D length of raw material that contains "net" and "waste" intervals. Using 2*n* cuts, sections of material can be removed so that less waste has to be processed later. For a given value of *n*, where should the cuts be placed so that the amount of waste that is removed is maximised? No greater than a given length *c* of "net" material is permitted to be cut away in total.

---

I have a (*j* * 1) matrix of 0s and 1s. The data is clustered, i.e. values will tend to be found grouped into repeated sections.

I would like to find the largest *n* intervals of repeated 0s, with the condition that the total number of 1s contained within all intervals combined does not exceed some predefined constant *c*.

I have found a significant amount written already on efficiently finding a solution when *c* = 0 (that is, when an interval of digits must not contain 1).

However when a string of repeated 0s is permitted to be "contaminated" with a small amount of 1s my instinct tells me this significantly complicates the problem. It strikes me as a kind of cutting-stock problem, but I hope someone can nevertheless suggest an algorithm that will assist in finding a decent solution.

Comment: Have you tried dynamic programming?  What decomposition into subproblems did you consider?  What progress have you made so far?

Comment: I felt the subproblem of c=0 would be an obvious place to start. This is simply tabulating the longest intervals of uninterrupted 0s. To improve calculation time I tried keeping track of the length of the nth longest string of 0s. If a 1 is encountered, skip forward by that many digits and check for 1 or 0 (as a longer substring of 0s is clearly not contained in that space). However, generalising this to allow some amount of net product to be cut away has got me stumped. Is it better to use all of the "allowance" to join two large but distant sections, or join many smaller but closer sections?

Comment: Let $f(i, k)$ be the minimum "net" material cut away in an optimal solution to the subproblem consisting of just the first $i$ elements ($i \le j$), using exactly $k$ pairs of cuts ($k \le n$).  You can calculate this from the minimum, over all $1 \le r < i$, of $\min(f(r, k-1) + g(r+1, i), f(r, k))$, if $g(x, y)$ is the amount of "net" material between positions $x$ and $y$, inclusive.  This can be done in $O(j^2 n)$ time.